# Linq query to find items that could be within a range

Tags: linq

I have an object Invoice which belongs to an Area:

```
public class Invoice : IEntity, IValidatableObject
    {
            ...

        public virtual int? AreaId { get; set; }
            ...
        // Navigation properties
        public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
            ...
    }
```

I also have a User object which can belong to multiple areas:

```
public class User : IEntity, INamedType
    {
        ...

        //Navigation properties
        public virtual ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

What I'm wanting to achieve is to get for a user all the invoices that belong to any of their areas. I tried writing it but it's not even close to right:

```
var invoices = _db.Invoices.Where(x => x.AreaId == user.Areas.Contains(z => z.Id));
```

Can anyone help me with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var invoices = _db.Invoices.Where(x =>  user.Areas.Any(z => z.Id == x.AreaId));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that should work:

```
var invoices = _db.Invoices.Where(x => user.Areas.Any(z => z.ID == x.AreaId))
```

Comment: Just a seconds ;) If only i didn't write that text above the query... :P